# Vim color black isn't black

Tags: colorscheme, color, iterm2

I have the following text in my `~/.vimrc`:

```
syntax on
colorscheme koehler
highlight ErrorMsg ctermbg=Red ctermfg=Black
```

however the error messages show like this:

[image]

The error message is gray on red, not black on red. How can I get it to display as black?

I know it is reading the commands in my `.vimrc` because I can change the text color to other colors, it's just that black doesn't show correctly.

I am using iTerm2.

Comment: typo `ctermfb`? BTW: What is the output of `:hi ErrorMsg`?

Comment: `ErrorMsg       xxx term=standout cterm=bold ctermfg=0 ctermbg=9 guifg=White
                   guibg=Red`

Comment: Terminal color number `0` is supposed to be black, might be the bold attribute, else you might need to configure your terminal correctly what colors it uses.

Comment: filbranden's suggestion of `cterm=NONE` fixed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should also include:

```
highlight ErrorMsg cterm=NONE
```

The `cterm` attributes often interact with the color settings and can end up having Vim picking a "bright" shade of the color.

The "koehler" theme ships with `cterm=bold`, which has this effect of using a bright color on many terminals, including iTerm2 (with default settings.)

You can inspect your settings by querying them, with:

```
:highlight ErrorMsg
```

I expect you'll see that `cterm=bold` is included there.

In order to remove that, simply set it to `NONE`.

You can do all these settings from a single command:

```
highlight ErrorMsg ctermbg=Red ctermfb=Black cterm=NONE
```